# Access macro did not run on the server when the database opened by a scheduled job

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled job on the server. The job is to run a batch file at night when I am logged off. It simply opens an Access database and runs a macro. I have used `/x` to do this, and all references to files are UNC, not via mapped drives.

When I run the batch file by double clicking on it, it runs and finishes smoothly, however the scheduled job does not seems to be working. It opens the database and leaves it open until next morning and the macro is not executed. I have to clear MSACCESS.EXE from the Task Manager next morning.

I have tried with VBScript and found same result.
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What user does the job run as?

Comment: Beside the user, when you run access file manually, does it ask you to enable macros or prompt for any action?

Comment: @Nath My admin has scheduled the job for me. I am basically logging in as me. The job runs at the time specified only when I am logged in but will not run if I log off.

Comment: @mGouda When I run the job by double clicking on the batch file, it runs and finishes the job (Access macro) smoothly without any prompt.

Comment: I suggest you enable logging in your batch and check what logs say. I am not sure how your batch runs. but if it is a windows service for example you can log to windows logs and check logs from windows event viewer